# Homebrew formula that only sets up launchd

Tags: homebrew, launchd, pbcopy

I want to create a homebrew formula that will only setup some launchd configurations. Specifically it will bind `/usr/bin/pbcopy` and `/usr/bin/pbpaste` to a port so that I can expose these to my remote development envirnoment.

Everything I have read about creating homebrew formula implies that they *must* download something though, which I don't really need to do. I just want to be able to create and link some plist files.

Am I missing something, is homebrew not the right tool for this? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Might you do better with a simple `netcat` one-liner - it is available as `nc` on OSX I think.

Comment: How do you mean using `netcat?` I can already bind `pbcopy` to a port using this launchd config - https://gist.github.com/olivernn/e298c3a5c32f33c550cb. I want to be able to package this as a homebrew formula to make it easy to install/uninstall.

Comment: Ok, cool, go with your solution :-) I don't know what your overall aim is, I merely meant that it might be easier to type `nc -l 2274 | pbcopy` or somesuch than to go to the trouble of making, installing and maintaining a homebrew package.

Comment: The thing is that my main dev environment is a linux host that I connect to over ssh, so I _always_ want `pbcopy` on my mac listening on a port which I forward to my dev box. On my mac I could just use netcat, but I'd need something to start that and keep it running, which would be launchd, at which point I'm back at this question! :)